# How can i put summarized value of multiple doubles into a list?

Tags: java, arrays

newbie here.

This is the code

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter Name of the event " + (i + 1) + " that the teams are entering");
    Tevent[i] = scan.next();
} // event names
            
for (int a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
    System.out.println("Enter rank of the team on the event"); // event ranks
    teamRank[i] = scan.nextInt();
    if (teamRank[i] > 3) {
        System.out.println("This team will not be awarded points");
    }
    if (teamRank[i] == 3) {
        System.out.println("5 points is granted for this event");
        teamScore[i] = teamScore[i] + 5;
    }
    if (teamRank[i] == 2) {
        System.out.println("10 points is granted for this event");
        teamScore[i] = teamScore[i] + 10;
    }
    if (teamRank[i] == 1) {
        System.out.println("20 points is granted for this event");
        teamScore[i] = teamScore[i] + 20;
    }
```

The code is supposed to ask for event name and then ask for the rank.

According to the rank, it is supposed to add points to the team on each event and then print out the summarized value.

Example:

- if I enter rank 1 5 times, instead of showing 100 it shows 20

I tried using multiple loops, it didn't work.

I feel like I am totally wrong on the code.
Maybe there's another way of doing this?
Can someone show me the way please :D thanks

Comment: Could it because of "for (int a = 0; a < 1; a++)" as this only runs once ?

Comment: The code should be formatted properly - this makes easier to see if the logic is wrong.  Here the loops are NOT nested, and the loop variable `i` is somehow used in the second loop, which contains ONLY one iteration.

Comment: Also, the code is not complete, there's no _list_ mentioned in the code, do you mean `teamRank` array?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An implementation with the fixes:

- use constant values to define the size of arrays and the number of ranking attempts
- replaced duplicated code in `if` with `switch` statement calculating `rank`
- fixed data input to handle [famous `Scanner` issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

```java
final int teamSize = 2;
String[] Tevent = new String[teamSize];
int[] teamScore = new int[teamSize];
int[] teamRank  = new int[teamSize];

final int rankCount = 3;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < Tevent.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter Name of the event " + (i + 1) + " that the teams are entering");
    Tevent[i] = scan.nextLine();
    
    for (int a = 0; a < rankCount; a++) {
        System.out.println("Enter rank of the team on the event");
        teamRank[i] = scan.nextInt();
        int rank = 0;
        switch (teamRank[i]) {
            case 3: rank =  5; break;
            case 2: rank = 10; break;
            case 1: rank = 20; break;
        }
        if (rank == 0) {
            System.out.println("This team will not be awarded points");
        } else {
            teamScore[i] += rank;
            System.out.println(rank + " points is granted for this event");
        }
    }
    if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("----");
}
System.out.println("Team ranks:  " + Arrays.toString(teamRank));
System.out.println("Team scores: " + Arrays.toString(teamScore));
```

Example run:

```
Enter Name of the event 1 that the teams are entering
event1
Enter rank of the team on the event
2 10 points is granted for this event
Enter rank of the team on the event
2 10 points is granted for this event
Enter rank of the team on the event
2
10 points is granted for this event
----
Enter Name of the event 2 that the teams are entering
event 2
Enter rank of the team on the event
1
20 points is granted for this event
Enter rank of the team on the event
3
5 points is granted for this event
Enter rank of the team on the event
3
5 points is granted for this event
----
Team ranks:  [2, 3]
Team scores: [30, 30]
```